# Rails render partial from sub-directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've just implemented the Devise Invitable gem in my rails app and now I'm having an issue getting my partials to render.  I imagine it's because of absolute vs. relative paths.

I'm hesitant to change much in my `application.html.erb` since all of my other views rely on the partials that are being rendered.  So, is there another way to make this all work?

Here is the directory tree:

```
app/
 -controllers/
 ---application_controller.rb
 ---users/
 -----invitations_controller.rb
 -views/
 ---layouts/
 -----application.html.erb
 -----_back_buttons.html.erb
 -----_footer.html.erb
 -----_navigation.html.erb
 ---users/
 -----invitations/
 -------new.html.erb
 -------edit.html.erb
```

In my `application.html.erb` file, I'm currently rendering views & partials with:

```
<%= render partial: 'layouts/navigation' %>
<%= render partial: 'layouts/topnav' %>
<%= render partial: 'layouts/tour' %>

<%= yield %>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/footer' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'footermanifest' %>
```

And in my new view `views/users/invitations/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= render partial: "/layouts/back_button" %>
... the form
```

**Notice the absolute reference to the partial here (/)**

This loads the `layouts/_back_button.html.erb` fine, but none of the other partials in `application.html.erb` load.  Basically, I have a pretty empty page with a form (courtesy of application.html.erb).

Am I doing something wrong in how I've nested the `views/users/invitations/new.html.erb` or something else?

**UPDATE**
Started thinking... since I don't want ppl creating a 'new' user account to see the navigation and everything, I am forcing a different layout for them in `controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == "new"
      "external_pages"
    else
      "application"
    end
end
```

So, is there a way to specify the `layout_by_resource` even further so that my `controller/user/invitation_controller.rb doesn't fall within this scope?

Comment: i'm hoping you mean `application.html.erb` and not `application.rb`

Comment: @maxple yes, sorry...

Comment: In the one example that works, you have a `/` (Slash) at the beginning of the partial path. I wonder if adding this to the others would work.

Comment: @maxple I did try that, but the leading `/` within `application.html.erb` still doesn't render the partials within the new views in`views/users/invitations/...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so while I was hoping for a little less 'repeat myself', but forcing the controller to render a different layout works:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :get_company_and_locations
  layout "application"

  def new
    ...
  end
end
```